# Download files in remote server using reverse proxy Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse

I have a server running with Nginx reverse proxy.

We have our application running in another server, which is served using this Nginx proxy. Below is the configuration I have used and its working fine.

```
location / {
                rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://10.0.0.121:8000;
        }
```

I would need to download a pdf file in the application machine (10.0.0.121) , which is under /home/ubuntu/app/pdf/data-2021-03-25.pdf.

How could I make the file in application machine downloadable from the proxy server, please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply install another nginx instance on `10.0.0.121` and configure it like this. NON-PROD READY!

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name ...;

  root /home/ubuntu/app/pdf;

  location = /data-2021-03-25.pdf {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

server {
  listen 8090;

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
}
```

Not tested but this server will handling the request serving the file. Then you could just use `proxy_pass` on the other server to proxy the request.

But beside from this option you can use a python, perl, php, java, nodejs, assembly or what ever programming language you want to use to open a http port and serve the file on an incoming request. Its really your choice.

just make sure if you're going for the proxy solution you are sanitizing the requests on your proxy. For example. With a small change in the setup above you could  cheat and get any other files from your home/app directory by sending an request like `curl -v localhost:8090/pdf/../other/file`. So make sure you are using the `root`(/home/ubuntu/app/pdf/) directive and set a location matching the pdf-file on the proxy-server as well.

That worked in my demo app.